# Change position Element news feed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to rotate every element in website like in the picture .
show from every 3 element rotate left to right every hour
and from element rotate down to top a day .. 
to implementation in one page and data still static not using php maybe juts using html, css and javascript

[image: Desain news feed]

I've tried to search in google but not find..
mybe give me reference link or your code ..  thx

Comment: You need provide what you have tried and what you are specifically having an issue with or your question will be closed.

Comment: It's not a good idea doing this just with HTML/JS/CSS since this depends on the user's time. Two different users may see different content simuntaneosly. The best option is make a server-side logic that renders the items correctly.

Comment: can you give me link reference ?